# C Blocks indirection and misalignment

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

The following code throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (specifically a general protection fault error) and I would like to know why you cannot misalign a block pointer and execute it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

void (^blocky)() = ^{
    printf("Hello!\n");
    printf("Hello Again!\n");
};

blocky = *(&blocky+1);

blocky = *(&blocky-1);
blocky();
return 0;
}
```

But the following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

void (^blocky)() = ^{
    printf("Hello!\n");
    printf("Hello Again!\n");
};

blocky = *(&blocky+1-1);
blocky();
return 0;
}
```

Edit (answer to misaligning code blocks):

If you treat a block like a structure, you can find that the value that points to the executable code in memory is offset 16 bytes from the start of the block and is 8 bytes long.

You are able to change this value effectively pointing execution to another place in memory. Generally, this will crash.

Assuming you know the specific address in memory for another piece of executable code, you may direct it there.

Why this is useful:
It isn't. Never do this. Really. Never.

Comment: Ummm. Maybe because it's a bad idea? So that there's protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer manipulation in the first example is wrong.  Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (^blocky_t)();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    blocky_t blocky = ^{
        printf("Hello!\n");
        printf("Hello Again!\n");
    };

    printf("blocky=%p\n", blocky);

    blocky = (blocky_t)((char *)blocky + 1);
    printf("blocky=%p\n", blocky);

    blocky = (blocky_t)((char *)blocky - 1);
    printf("blocky=%p\n", blocky);

    blocky();
    return 0;
}

$ clang -o blocky blocky.c
$ ./blocky
blocky=0x10574d040
blocky=0x10574d041
blocky=0x10574d040
Hello!
Hello Again!
```

When I ran your code, I got:

```
blocky=0x10e0ba040
blocky=0x7fff51b46c10
blocky=0x1300000000
```

Where:

- The first address is within the `__TEXT` segment of the program.
- The second address is near the stack.
- The third is who-knows-where.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to cast it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question really has nothing to do with blocks. You're just manipulating pointers to local variables in a way that doesn't make sense.

First, you never use the block pointer that you assign to `blocky`. You take the address of the local variable `blocky` on the stack, and then add one word to it, and dereference it. Depending on the architecture, the stack probably grows down, which means this is before all the variables on the stack frame, and is probably the return address of the current stack frame. Or it may be something else. You then assign this value to `blocky`.

Then, you take the address of the local variable `blocky` on the stack again, and then subtract one word from it, and dereference it. Again, assuming the stack grows down, this might be past the end of the current stack frame, which would be garbage. You then assign this value to `blocky`. You then try to run this as a pointer to a block. Of course this doesn't work.

In the second piece of code, you take the address of the local variable `blocky` on the stack again, and then add and subtract one word from it (which of course is the pointer to the local variable `blocky` again), and dereference it (which is the value of `blocky`), and assign it to `blocky`. This operation does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that I never used the block pointer assigned to blocky?

Comment: @Wrsford: Well, after you assign it (`void (^blocky)() = ...`), you then assign something else to it `blocky = ...`. The only thing that happens in between is you take the address of the local variable `blocky`. That's not using the value of the variable.